# SQL Server Management Studio - Не удалось подключиться к серверу

Tags: sql-server

Очень долго искал решение этой проблемы, перепробовал все способы с ютуба и советы со Стэка в похожих темах - не помогли.

Пробовал, но не помогло:

1. Сменить язык системы на UTC-8;
2. Задать собственное название сервера;
3. Сменить пользователя;
4. Открыть программу от имени администратора;
5. Отредактировать реестр;
6. Открыть порт;

[image: Та самая ошибка]

Comment: В поле "server name" указывается адрес сервера и экземляр СУБД. По скрину могу предположить, что сервер локальный. И скорее всего, параметры подключения вы сами настраивали в процессе установки.